# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Windows 8.1 Update 1 Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, system-installation

I downloaded the ubuntu 14.04 iso image file, I need to install it in a partition giving it at least 40GB (My HD is 1TB).
Since I've never formatted this computer, it is subdivided in 6 partitions:

800 MB - Recovery;
260 MB - EFI;
149,56 GB - C: - Windows Partition;
140MB - Recovery;
758,56 GB - D: - Data;
21,70 GB - Recovery;

I'd like to install ubuntu in D, but I have a question:
Is there any risk to lose any data by subdividing the D: partition?
Will I be able in future, if needed, to delete ubuntu and recover the whole D: partition?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu to a partition, firstly it clear all data at that partition so you shouldn't do it. :)
You can easily seperate a 40GB partition from D: partition in Windows. You can see how you seperate partition on Windows here : http://www.howtogeek.com/172580/how-to-create-a-separate-data-partition-for-windows/ (look "After Installing Windows" part)

Comment: So if I separate 40 GB from D directly in Windows and I try installing ubuntu in that 40 GB partition everything else will work normally?
Also, since I have windows 8.1, will ubuntu show up normally or do I need to edit something in the BIOS?
Thanks :)

Comment: Yes everything will work normally, because the 40GB partition will be an independent partition. :) Also, you should make some little settings to use Windos8.1 and Ubuntu at the same time. In fact, now I am using both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS as lots of people do. :) You just need a little guide like this : http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html?m=1